# SQL - How to substitute a result which was retrieved by a SELECT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose you have 2 tables,

```
Citizen
Admin
```

An Admin is inherently a Citizen, so Admin has a FK into Citizen's PK.
Next when a Citizen entry is created, the entry records which Admin entered it.

Citizen includes details like the citizen's name, whereas admin includes other details not related to a citizen's details.

So then I have a query,

```
SELECT ctzName, ctzEnteredByID
FROM Citizen
INNER JOIN Admin
ON ctzPK = admPK
WHERE ctzPK = 2
```

This query returns the name of the Citizen and the ID of the Admin who created the Citizen entry. In this case that ID would be admPK/ctzPK of the Admin. As an example, let's say the Citizen table has 2 entries,

```
ctzPK = 1, ctzName = Chris, ctzEnteredByID = 0
ctzPK = 2, ctzName = John, ctzEnteredByID = 1
```

then this query returns,

```
John, 1
```

However, I want to print the name of the Admin who entered it as well. So I want my result to be

```
John, 1, Chris
```

I've tried `SELECT`ing this value as a condition in `WHERE`, but to no avail. How do you do this type of substitution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another two `INNER JOIN` (and alias the extant table references) to get the data for the `subjectCitizen.ctzEnteredByID`.

Like so:

```sql
SELECT

    subjectCitizen.ctzName        AS "Subject Citizen Name",
    subjectCitizen.ctzEnteredByID AS "Subject Citizen's data entered by (ID)",
    makerCitizen.ctzName          AS "Subject Citizen's data entered by (Name)"

FROM
    -- Subject data:
    dbo.Citizen AS subjectCitizen
    INNER JOIN dbo.Admin AS subjectAdmin ON
        subjectCitizen.ctzPK = subjectAdmin.admPK

    -- Subject's creator:
    INNER JOIN dbo.Admin AS maker ON
        maker.admPK = subjectCitizen.ctzEnteredByID

    INNER JOIN dbo.Citizen AS makerCitizen ON
        maker.admPK = makerCitizen.ctzPK

WHERE
    subjectCitizen.ctzPK = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a foreign key on citizen table like "AdminId" , then your select query changes to this :

```
SELECT ctz.Name, ctz.AdminId, ad.Name
FROM Citizen ctz
INNER JOIN Admin ad
ON ctz.AdminId = ad.Id
WHERE ctz.Id = 2
```